# How to optimally find all fields that contain an email address

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I would like to return the column names for all columns containing an email address (`... LIKE '%@%.%'`). Is there a way to search fields for emails without doing it exhaustively? That is as soon as one email instance is found in the field the next is searched as oppose to looking at all its values? This is to scale better to large databases.

In the case below 'Foo' and 'Email' should be returned without searching all their records.

[image: Example data]

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUM(Foo LIKE '%@%.%') > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Foo,
    CASE WHEN SUM(Bar LIKE '%@%.%') > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Bar,
    CASE WHEN SUM(Email LIKE '%@%.%') > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Email,
    CASE WHEN SUM(Name LIKE '%@%.%') > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Name
FROM yourTable;
```